# is it possible to control status bar position under iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, statusbar

I want to know if it possible to control the position of the status bar with iOS 8 SDK? 
I know i can use `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method, but now with the iOS 8 SDK if i change the orientation of the rootViewController all child viewController will take the same orientation because of `viewWillTransitionToSize` method.

Somebody can help me ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the apple docs here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html

> Don’t create a custom status bar. Users depend on the consistency of the system-provided status bar. Although you might hide the status bar in your app, it’s not appropriate to create custom UI that takes its place

This means that no, you cannot and should not change the default position of the status bar or put anything under it or around it that would obscure it. You can hide it or change its default appearance if you like, that is explained in the docs.